# VBA walk through multidimensional array (dimensions limited by system only!)

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array

Via Google I found no function that can emit a multidimensional array as structured text. VBA arrays behave somewhat bulky in this respect, if you want to iterate through a multidimensional array.
Corrective suggestions, answers and / or comments are welcome.

So here's my Code suggestion - For free private Use (not excessively tested!):

```
'**********************************************************************************************************
' Helper-Function: emits a multidimensional array as structured text (c) 2018 F. Heinemann, Freiburg, Germany
Function Arr2Str(ByVal aArr As Variant, Optional ByVal nLevel As Long = 0, Optional ByVal nMaxDim As Long = 0) As String
   Dim cRet As String
   Dim nI, nK  As Long
   Dim nCount1 As Long

   On Error Resume Next
   Arr2Str = ""
   cRet = ""
   nMaxDim = MaxUboundFH(aArr)
   nCount1 = UboundFH(aArr, nMaxDim)
   If nCount1 = -1 Then
      Debug.Print "Error: wrong MaxDim! [" & CStr(nMaxDim) & "]"
      Exit Function
   End If
   For nI = LBound(aArr) To UBound(aArr)
      cRet = cRet & Space(nLevel) & "- " & "[" & nI & "]: " & aArr(nI) & vbCrLf
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
         GoTo NextIteration_nI
      End If
      nCount1 = UboundFH(aArr, nMaxDim)
      For nK = 0 To nCount1 + 1
         If IsArrayFH(aArr, nI, nK) = True Then
            cRet = cRet & Arr2Str(aArr(nI, nK), nLevel + 1, nMaxDim - 1)
         Else
            cRet = cRet & Space(nLevel) & "- " & "[" & nI & "]: " & aArr(nI, nK) & vbCrLf
         End If
      Next nK
NextIteration_nI:
   Next nI
   Arr2Str = cRet
End Function

Function MaxUboundFH(ByRef aArr As Variant) As Long
   Dim nI, nDimGet As Long

   MaxUboundFH = 1
   On Error GoTo MaxUboundFH_Error

   For nI = 2 To 64
      nDimGet = UBound(aArr, nI)
      MaxUboundFH = nI
      Exit Function
   Next nI

   Exit Function
MaxUboundFH_Error:

End Function

Function UboundFH(ByRef aArr As Variant, ByVal nDim As Long) As Long
   Dim nDimGet As Long

   UboundFH = -1
   On Error GoTo UboundFH_Error
   nDimGet = UBound(aArr, nDim)
   UboundFH = nDimGet
   Exit Function

UboundFH_Error:
   UboundFH = -1
End Function

Function IsArrayFH(ByRef aArr As Variant, ByVal nIndex1 As Long, ByVal nIndex2 As Long) As Boolean

   IsArrayFH = False
   On Error GoTo IsArrayFH_Error
   If IsArray(aArr(nIndex1, nIndex2)) = True Then
      IsArrayFH = True
      Exit Function
   End If
IsArrayFH_Error:
   IsArrayFH = False
End Function
```

Comment: You dont have a question?

Comment: Maybe post it on codereview. Also, do you not need to clear the error after using `On Error GoTo`? I would have thought that even though `VBA.Strings.Join()` can't handle multidimensional arrays, joining an array of arrays would be a more efficient workaround to this limitation than recursively calling the Arr2Str function and using the concatenation operator `&` (which creates copies of the string each time due to string handling in VBA). I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, I did not optimize the handling of errors. Likewise, one has to incorporate the checking of the array on different data types.
Sure, the recursion produces something like that; but I also want to have a string at the end.
I just posted the code because I can not find such a feature on the internet right now - but maybe I'm an inefficient Google user.